# looking for a novel way to keep client data sync'ed with server data

Tags: mysql, vb.net, client-server

I am building an application in VB.Net using MySQL databases on both the clients and server. I will have multiple clients (say 10 to 20) using the system at a time. As clients do work locally, they will need to send their data up to the central server. They will also get back any data that has been changed by any other client since they last checked. So all clients will have all the same data.

I am looking for a system that will speed up the sync process. Basically I need each client to insert any new data they have into the central db, and make updates (on the central db) to any existing data that they have changed locally. They also need to get any new records that exist on the central db that they don't currently have and update their local records with the ones that were changed on the central db by other clients.

I am currently using a bit field to identify the clients. Whenever a client changes something on the central db, it changes their bit. This way, when a client sync's with the server, it only gets records that have their bit set to 0. Then I make the changes locally and reset their bit back to 1.

This works fine and fast except that it is limiting. I can only have a set number of total clients (64 to be exact) and the more clients I have the slower the syncing because of the increased size of the bit field. I don't expect to ever have any more than about 30 clients at a time, but I really don't like the idea that it has a maximum.

I can check dates on records instead of bits when syncing, but this is very slow. However, it has no limit on the number of clients.

Does anyone know of a good way to do this that is both fast and unlimited?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just read and write directly to the central database? If required you can just work on the data using a disconnected dataset:

http://www.vbmigration.com/BookChapters/ProgrammingVBNET_Chap21.pdf